# Default full name format in Active Directory

Tags: active-directory

When I create a new account in Active Directory, I enter the new user's first name and last name, and it auto-fills the full name in the form "First Last". Can I set AD to use "Last, First" instead?  The domain controller is currently Server 2003.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You'll need to edit the `createDialog` attribute of the `displaySpecifier` named `CN=user-Display` to alter the default format in ADUC.

1. Launch `adsiedit.msc`
2. Right-click the root and choose "Connect to..."
3. On the "Select well known Naming Context" choose "Configuration"
4. Expand "Configuration", on the left pane and drill down:

   - CN=Configuration,DC=example,DC=com
   - CN=DisplaySpecifiers
   - CN=409 (Note this is for EN-US, you need to select your domain's locale)
   - CN=user-Display
5. Open the properties of this specifier.
6. Change the `createDialog` attribute to `%<sn>, %<givenName>`

This is documented, in more detail, in MS support Article ID: 250455

[How to change display names of Active Directory users](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/250455).

Edit:  To answer, possibly, your next question, you can change the existing `displayName` attributes of users with the following Powershell.

The LDAP filter will select users with a populated `displayName`, but will exclude users if `displayName` contains a comma.

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(objectCategory=person)(!displayName=*,*)(displayName=*))" |
    ForEach-Object {  
        Set-ADUser $_ -DisplayName "$($_.Surname), $($_.givenName)"
    }
```

Comment: You can as @jscott provided, but make sure you have a very clear, very well thought out business reason for making a schema change like this. Many utilities and applications use the default. Generally speaking, this change isn't a breaking change (its usually a sort order or display issue), but it is painful when it occurs.

Comment: @JimB Changing an object in the `Configuration` partition is ***not*** a schema change, and nothing enforces the display name format - it's simple to change the display name away from the auto-generated one after or even during user creation.  This change is just a "convenience" one to prevent needing to manually edit the display name that's generated when you input the first name, last name, and initial.

Comment: @ShaneMadden Updated to remove my misuse of terminology -- apologies.

Comment: This is great! It always irked me to have to change the display name format during user creation, can't wait to implement this one.

Comment: @ShaneMadden Correct it's not a schema change (I wasn't about to write a missive on what is and isnt a schema change) however this is certainly not a "convienience" change and can break things that are not exactly up to spec (I'm looking at you Cisco Unity...) in they way they lookup and provide names