# Active Directory: Handle Suffixes in a User's Last Name?

Tags: active-directory

So I've never come across this before.  We have two users on our network that are related and share the same first and last names.  Our username naming policy dictates the younger user will have his middle initial used to distinguish usernames but I have a question related more on the display and storage of attributes.

How do you handle the storage of suffixes such as Jr., III, etc.?  Do you simply append them to the last name or is there a different attribute designed to handle this information?

I'm just not sure on best practice or common convention here.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [Active Directory Schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675085(v=vs.85).aspx) defines an attribute [`Generation-Qualifier`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675717(v=vs.85).aspx) for exactly this purpose.

Your employer may decide to include the suffix string in other attributes such as [`Canonical-Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675436(v=vs.85).aspx), [`Sam-Account-Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679635(v=vs.85).aspx), [`User-Principal-Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680857(v=vs.85).aspx).  You may even make modifications to the `Configuration` partition to "automate" such inclusions, but that is outside the scope of your question.  See [Default full name format in Active Directory](https://serverfault.com/questions/354275/default-full-name-format-in-active-directory/354284) for an example.

Comment: Perfect! Yea, I'm familiar with the automated tasks to override the default behaviors.  The link you provided in the generation-qualifier was great!

Answer (score 1):

It's your environment, so I would do whatever makes you feel comfortable and would make it easier to remember.  For me personally, I would add jr and use number 3 instead of III.

Comment: But does AD provide a standard way to store this value, that was the question.

Comment: I don't think so, since you have to physically enter AD's username.