# Change active directory display name format in PowerShell?

Tags: active-directory, powershell

Is there a way, using PowerShell, to change the AD format of the usernames to `Lastname, Firstname`?

I know how to do it manually like the answer given [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/354275/default-full-name-format-in-active-directory).  I am trying to see if I can add this to a script that I am putting together.

Thanks!

***Edit***

After digging a little deeper from this article [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4231.working-with-active-directory-using-powershell-adsi-adapter.aspx) I was able to figure it out.

```
$domain = $env:USERDOMAIN
$uddn = "cn=user-display,cn=409,cn=displayspecifiers,cn=configuration,dc=$domain,dc=com"
$ud = [ADSI]"LDAP:// $uddn "
$ud.Put("createDialog","%<sn>, %<givenName>")
$ud.SetInfo()
```

Comment: Are you asking if you can modify the `createDialog` attribute using PowerShell?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I am trying to accomplish if possible.

Comment: Yes, you can modify the `createDialog` attribute using PowerShell. What have you tried? Which part isn't working? Please add any code as an edit to your question.

Comment: I am still fairly new to powershell.  I have not written this part of the script yet as I have not been able to find any powershell examples online as to how to do it. The rest of the script add's OU's, Groups and Users things of that nature. Any guidance on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Cool, glad you resolved this. You should post your answer as such so you can [mark it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I can't accept it for another day, but I will mark it when it allows me to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging a little deeper from this article [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4231.working-with-active-directory-using-powershell-adsi-adapter.aspx) I was able to figure it out. Here is what I came up with.

```
$domain = $env:USERDOMAIN
$uddn = "cn=user-display,cn=409,cn=displayspecifiers,cn=configuration,dc=$domain,dc=com"
$ud = [ADSI]"LDAP:// $uddn "
$ud.Put("createDialog","%<sn>, %<givenName>")
$ud.SetInfo()
```