# Change AD Display name from Lastname, Firstname to Firstname Lastname

Tags: active-directory, powershell

My organization wants to change the Display name format to `Firstname Lastname` instead of `Lastname, Firstname`

I already change the format for creating new users in the ADSI settings. But want to change all current users display name to `Firstname Lastname`

I found a script in: [Default full name format in Active Directory](https://serverfault.com/questions/354275/default-full-name-format-in-active-directory)

```powershell
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(objectCategory=person)(!displayName=*,*)(displayName=*))" |
ForEach-Object {  
    Set-ADUser $_ -DisplayName "$($_.Surname), $($_.givenName)"
}
```

This change it from `Firstname Lastname` to `Lastname, Firstname`. I want to do a reverse, so I tweak this script to:

```powershell
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(objectCategory=person)(!displayName=*,*)(displayName=*))" |
ForEach-Object {  
    Set-ADUser $_ -DisplayName "$($_.givenName) $($_.Surname)"
}
```

But my AD users have still a display name like `Lastname, Firstname`. PS do not give any warnings or errors and did a refresh in AD.

Do someone knows a trick to change all AD users to `Firstname Lastname` as Displayname?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the filter. The string `(!displayName=*,*)` indicates that only user who currently **don't** have a `,` in their displayname should be changed. You want the inverse, so you need to remove the `!`.

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(objectCategory=person)(displayName=*,*))" |
ForEach-Object {  
    Set-ADUser $_ -DisplayName "$($_.givenName) $($_.Surname)"
}
```

Comment: It works! Thank you =] I also notice that the wildcard gets deleted '(displayName=*)' from the filter. Why is that?

Comment: Because it's redundant. `displayname=*` filters for all objects where the displayname is not empty. If it contains a `,` it is not empty, so it's no use to check that again.

Comment: Thanks again, very helpful explanation.